# [tinymce]TinyMCE version 6 editor does not appear on older iPad Mini running iPadOS 12.x

Tags: ipad, tinymce

I recently updated our hosted sites to use TinyMCE 6 after having run version 5.x successfully for a while.  However, it now appears that version 6 will not load properly on an iPad Mini (Gen 2) that runs iPadOS 12. Unfortunately, this device is older and cannot be updated to a newer version of iPadOS.  The editor does load properly on an iPhone running iOS 16.x and an iPad Pro running 16.x.  It also continues to work on a newer Android phone and the major desktop PC browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and Safari).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TinyMCE 5 may run on iPad OS 12 but is [only supported on iPad OS 13 or higher](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/mobile/#supportedmobileplatforms).

TinyMCE 6 is officially [supported on iPad OS 14 or higher](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/support/#supported-mobile-platforms).